# CSS second and third background not showing

Tags: css, background-image

I have an element which has 3 backgrounds. One which repeats along the x-axis once at the top.
The second should show once in the top left corner and the third in the top right corner.

But the second and third backgrounds are not showing.

Here is the CSS:

```
section.services .container header {
    background: url('../images/style/header_gradient.jpg'),
                url('../images/style/header_gradient_cover_left.png'),
                url('../images/style/header_gradient_cover_right.png');
    background-position: left top, left top, right top;
    background-repeat: repeat-x, no-repeat, no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: As @pzin mentioned, when using multiple background images, the order of the images is counter-intuitive. They're displayed in the reverse order in which they're listed. The one listed first is displayed last and goes on top. It may be easier to coordinate this using the shorthand syntax: `background: url(...) no-repeat left top, url(...) no-repeat right top, url(...) repeat-x left top;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the **order of the backgrounds are as they appear in your rule**. This means, the first one is always on the top, and the last one behind every one else. So you should put the first one as the last one so that the one that repeats over the x axis is not overlapping the others:

```
section.services .container header {
  background-image: url('../images/style/header_gradient_cover_left.png'),
                    url('../images/style/header_gradient_cover_right.png'),
                    url('../images/style/header_gradient.jpg');
  background-position: left top, right top, left top;
  background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat, repeat-x;
}
```

Additionally, to have a more organized/cleaner code, I would change `background` to `background-image` as I did.

Answer (score 1):

> Additionally, to have a more organized/cleaner code, I would change
>   background to background-image as I did.

Keep in mind that the white background from your browser might override the images if the element name is 'background-image' instead of 'background'.

I know that it's cleaner code but it somehow messed up my images.

Answer (score 0):

All Images are overlapping each other. Try disabling one by one in firebug and then check